# How to export data from file into variable inside bash script?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I need save into variable the file content (json string).

I try several methods, in particular:

```
#!/bin/bash

myjson=cat path-to-file/file.json
```

but nothing not work.

How to correctly implement this task?

Comment: mjson=\`cat patch/file.jsn\`  (backticks cause the command's output to replace the command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

myjson=$(cat patch/file.jsn)
```